# Passing an integer between Activities Doesn’t return the correct value?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I’m using Kotlin and trying to return a number from two Activities.
So from MainActivity I get a click (Searchbutton), this starts up my second activity: SearchActivity. When a click happens it then (should!) returns the number 59 to the MainActivity, which I should be able to see in Log.d.

What I actually see is I get the default value “0” being returned to MainActivity?
I’m assuming that the default value indicates that the value hasn’t been passed through the two activities?

Any help really appreciated!

*MainActivity.java*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            var gotthisInt = intent.getIntExtra("MY_KEY", 1);
            Log.d("TAG", "What was received= " + gotthisInt)
        }
    }
}
```

*SearchActivity.java*

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container)

        Searchbutton2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@SearchActivity, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("MY_KEY", 59)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is a bit confusing. Bear in mind that `intent` will only map to `getIntent()` in Kotlin if there is no property or local variable named `intent`. It is difficult to tell due to the code formatting, but it feels like your first set of code is declaring an `intent` variable, and then you are winding up calling `getIntExtra()` on that `intent` variable instead of the result of `getIntent()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Android to pass data between Activity, you should use [startActivityForResult(Intent, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)). So change your code to.

*MainActivity.java*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val gotthisInt = data?.getIntExtra("MY_KEY", 1) ?: 1
                Log.d("TAG", "What was received = $gotthisInt")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*SearchActivity.java*

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container)

        Searchbutton2.setOnClickListener {
            val data = Intent().apply { putExtra("MY_KEY", 59) }
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Winny good to hear that. by the way if this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as answer. It will help me improving my answers in the future.